# SQL Server Agent user/password login for network

Tags: sql-server, credentials, sql-server-agent

I have a job that create a BCK file and transfer it over network to another machine, I need to change the machine by replacing the ip address in the sql server agent job,

The issue is I'm unable to find where the credentials are set to the old server so I can either update them or remove and add credentials to new server

when I run this command with old ip it works fine

```
dbo.xp_cmdshell 'copy C:\test.txt \\<OLD_IP>\backups'
```

> 1 file(s) copied.

it works fine, but with the new ip address it says

> The user name or password is incorrect

also the output of following query is also empty

```
select * from [msdb].[dbo].[sysproxies]
```

Comment: In general, it's bad practice to embed IP addresses into something like a script.  Instead use a host name.  This is because that even though your network may not make use of DHCP, IP addresses may change in the future, and there is a risk that your code will then fail.

Comment: True sir, but my issue is where can I find and change the username and password of that machine,?

Comment: You can find the Windows account that owns the SQL Server Agent service process by going to the Services applet (Start menu -> Run -> services.msc), and then find the entry for "SQL Server Agent ([instance name])". If you are running a default instance, the instance name will be "MSSQLSERVER".

Comment: the `log on as` user you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That account will need write privileges in the folder to which you're attempting to copy the file.